# Execute a command which will check if the disk space on somepartion is greater than 1 KB, return -1 else return 0

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Execute a command which will check if the disk space on somepartion is greater than `1 KB`, return `-1` else return `0`

For ex:

```
df| tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'
```

This command returns available space on root partition and this command returns 23% space on my disk.

I want it return `-1` if the space is less than `1 KB`  else return `0`

and we can not write sh file for this so i want `0` and `-1` answer through the command

UPDATED
it should exit with that return code means it should exit with returncode 0 or -1

Comment: If there is less than 1kB of space on your root partition, it is fairly unlikely that you will be able to even run this!

Comment: Plus I suspect having less than 1KB means 0 in practice - `stat -f /` reports my fundamental block size as 4096.

Comment: And when you say "return" do you mean "print out to stdout" or "print out to stderr" or "set the exit code"????

Comment: -1 is not a well-defined return code, shell exit codes are 0-255.  Some implementations may coerce -1 to 255 but it's technically an error to try to use a signed integer.  For the record, 0 is success, so that part is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may do:

```
df | awk 'END {print ($4<1024?"-1":"0")}'
0
```

You can change the number to any that fits your need.
`END` is used to get last line, instead of `tail`

---

To get it into an exit/return code do:

```
(exit $(df | awk 'END {print ($4<1024?"-1":"0")}')); echo "$?"
```

PS `exit -1` will give `255`

Comment: $4 is a column of 1K-sized blocks, so you're testing here for 1024KB.

Comment: @Jotne Thanks for your answer but it should exit with that return code means it should exit with returncode 0 or -1

Comment: @Spacedman so it shoud be some like `awk 'END {print ($4<1?"-1":"0")}'` this then.

Comment: @Jotne it is always returning the last option mean whether the last argument is -1 or 0 it always returns last option

Comment: @ShekharSaxena not sure what you mean.  See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `stat` to get the available blocks and the block size, create an expression and pipe into `bc`.

Here I'm testing it with a value of 10240 **bytes** on a couple of FS, one with less than that free and one with more:

```
$ stat -f /sys/fs/cgroup -c "(%a * %s >= 10240) - 1" | bc
-1
$ stat -f / -c "(%a * %s >= 10240) - 1" | bc
0
```

Adjust the 10240 to your wanted value **in bytes**.

Here's the conventional `df` output:

```
$ df /
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       11440712 5517040   5319464  51% /
$ df /sys/fs/cgroup/
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
none                   4     0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

The corresponding `stat` being based on:

```
$ stat -f / -c "%a * %s / 1024" | bc
5319464
```

Note that using this instead of `awk` to parse the output of `df` is less fragile to possible output format changes of `df`.

To set the exit code from a script, capturing the output looks ok:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Testing $@

exit `stat -f $@ -c "(%a * %s >= 10240) - 1" | bc`
```

Note you get 255 and not -1 returned - but then **-1 is out of range** since exit codes can only be 0 to 255.

```
$ ./sizer.sh /sys/fs/cgroup/
Testing /sys/fs/cgroup/
$ echo $?
255
$ ./sizer.sh /
Testing /
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't want any script.i want only single command

Comment: You've got the single command. What do you want to do with it? Put a bit more context in your question.